# Is there a way to define a name for a python application using tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

So I created an application in Python, and I used the tkinter python library in it using

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter.ttk import *
```

and I had no problems with that, but the application name ended up being Tk.  I'm not sure if this was set by default, or just my IDE (vs code) guessing the application name based on the fact that I'm using the tkinter python library in it. I've been looking around to try and find a way to change the application name using tkinter, but I haven't found anything yet. Can someone please help me?

Comment: Something like `root = Tk(); root.title('my app')` should work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to give the application a name via `root.title`

```
import tkinter as tk

root = tk.Tk()
root.title('Your name')
root.mainloop()
```